# I need to calculate the number of holidays, falling on working days only, between two dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table, called Holidays, which lists all the dates classed as a holiday:

```
Date
01/01/2020
10/04/2020
13/04/2020
```

I have a table called employees, which shows an employee's working days, in a 7 digit syntax, where 0 is a working day and 1 is not a working day. It goes from Monday to Sunday. So '0000011' would mean that person works on Monday to Friday, and does not work on Saturday/Sunday.

```
Code     WorkingDays
A1       0000011
B1       1000111
```

I have a table of date ranges as such:

```
From         To          Employee
01/01/2020   31/05/2020  A1
01/01/2020   31/05/2020  B1
```

What I would like to return is:

```
From         To          Employee    Holidays
01/01/2020   31/05/2020  A1          3
01/01/2020   31/05/2020  B1          0
```

Employee A1 - there are 3 Holidays which fall between those two dates and are also working days
Employee B1 - there are no Holidays which fall between those two dates and are also working days

I need something similar to the NETWORKDAYS.INTL function, but instead of calculating working days I need it to calculate holidays somehow. Is this possible?

Comment: Find the total days then subtract weekend days the compare with number of days worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use NETWORKDAYS.INTL twice, one with just the weekends and the other that include the holidays and subtract the later from the prior:

```
=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(D2,E2,C2)-NETWORKDAYS.INTL(D2,E2,C2,$A$2:$A$4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd think maybe `SUMPRODUCT` is a good alternative to what you are looking for:

[image]

Formula in `G2`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A$4>=D2)*(A$2:A$4<=E2)*(MID(C2,WEEKDAY(A$2:A$4,2),1)="0"))
```

Drag down.

Comment: So as you see, I think correct would be `1` for `G3` since `WEEKDAY(A2,2)` returns `3` and that seems to be a workday for `B1`.